# Ubuntu stuck in shotdown

Tags: shutdown

My Ubuntu 16.04 **stuck in shutdown** some times when i use much of my memory(RAM).
It sometimes shutdown how i described before when my usage is small not time but also ram and swap usage is high it wont shutdown in splash but i removed splash from grub file. but it will restart by

> *ctrl + alt + print scr + B*

.
**I've tied** any thing i could find such removing quiet-splash from grub,...
Because it some time happens finding right answer is hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved with reinstalling a newer version of Ubuntu.